# Changing the font size of the selected drop down menu in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to change the font size of the option in the selected dropdown menu in css?

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="role">نقش پرسنل :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <select class="form-control" id="role" name="SelectedRoles">
                        <option selected>معاونت مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید</option>
                        @foreach (var item in Roles)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.RoleId"> @item.RoleTitle</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selection option we can apply `font-size` as :

```
.form-control ::selection option {
  font-size: 16px !important;  /*you can replace it with desired font size */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#role{ font-size: 20px !important; } // this will override any default values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
select#role {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="role">نقش پرسنل :</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <select class="form-control" id="role" name="SelectedRoles">
    <option selected>معاونت مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید</option>
       @foreach (var item in Roles)
       {
          <option value="@item.RoleId"> @item.RoleTitle</option>
       }
   </select>
 </div>
```